# Changing visibility of Log-out button from serverasp

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm now building a site including database of users. I want to add "log-out" button on the menu if the session exists. I thought that after checking session exist I would change the visibility property in the css. How can I do that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok how about something like this:

javascript:

```
PageMethods.IsSessionActive(isActive, onSuccess, onError);

function onSuccess(result) {
  if (result == "true") {
  //logic where the logout button is set to visible
  } else {
    //set to hidden
  }
}
```

C# server side web method:

```
[WebMethod] public static string IsSessionActive(string isActive) {  
//check if session is active   //is active set isActive = "true";

return isActive; }
```

Comment: I know I can do that in css but I want the server to change this property in the css depanding on existence of session...

Comment: I would try and keep server and client stuff separate. Thats what I usually do anyways.

Comment: I did exactly as you staid but vs calims in c# side "isActive does not exist in correct context".
The code in the server is this (maybe I misunderstood):

Comment: Ok, so I updated what you had pasted. The code behind page is here : http://pastebin.ca/2343481 and the aspx page is here : http://pastebin.ca/2343494 . I'm not sure what you wanted to use to fire the event checking for the session, so as an example I just placed it in a button click event.